# how to generate link from mention @username and put link in description with multiple links and mention name laravel

Tags: php, regex, laravel, codeigniter, mention

I want to generate a link form comment.

here two types of links generate from comment.

```
$string = "Hello @username you need to check this http://github.com and @username you need to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask";
```

the mentioned username and link in not require every time.

I got a solution for links to follow.

```
$comment_with_link = preg_replace('/\b(https?|ftp|file):\/\/[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|]/i',"<a href=\"\\0\">\\0</a>",$string);
```

but now I need to with @username any suggestion ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$comment_with_link = preg_replace('/\b(https?|ftp|file):\/\/[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|]/i',"<a href=\"\\0\">\\0</a>",$string); //for links
$comment_with_link = preg_replace("/\b(@(\w+))/"," <a href='https://example.com/users/\1'>\0</a> ", $comment_with_link); //for users
$comment_with_link = preg_replace("/\b(#(\w+))/"," <a href='https://example.com/colleges/\1'>\0</a> ", $comment_with_link); //for colleges
//note: first replace link then the mention
```

**Sample output**

```
Helo @user1 from #college1, visit https://example.com   ----> Helo <a href="https://example.com/users/user1">@user1</a> from <a href="https://example.com/colleges/college1">#college1</a>, visit <a href="https://example.com">https://example.com</a>
```

Comment: Hello @dum, Thanks for answering, but I need both in one regex.

Comment: Hello @dum, That's look cool, I need one more help, when In comment mention any `#college name` it's redirect like `username` all in one comments. Can you give me any suggestions?

Comment: Updated for colleges.

Answer (score 0):

If the username is not present every time, you could make that part optional and make use of 2 capturing groups and [preg_replace_callback](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php).

In the callback check if the value for group 1 (the username) is not empty and use the group values to assemble the values of the link.

```
(?<!\S)(?:(@[^\s@]+)(?!\S)[^h]*(?:h(?!ttp)[^h]*)*+)?\K((?:https?|ftp|file)://\S+)
```

**Explanation**

- `(?<!\S)` Assert a left whitspace boundary
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `(@[^\s@]+)` Capture **group 1** Match a username
  - `(?!\S)` Assert a right whitespace boundary
  - `[^h]*` Match 0+ times any char except `h`
  - `(?:` Non capture group

    - `h(?!ttp)[^h]*` Match `h` only when not directly followed by `ttp`
  - `)*+` Close group and repeat 0+ times using a [possessive quantifier](https://www.regular-expressions.info/possessive.html)
- `)?` Close group and make it option for the username
- `\K` Forget what was matched
- `(` Capture **group 2**

  - `(?:https?|ftp|file)` Match the protocol
  - `://\S+` Match `://` followed by 1+ times a non whitespace char
- `)` Close group 2

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/bysKzt/1) | [Php demo](https://3v4l.org/6kCW8)

```
$string = <<<STR
Hello @username you need to check this http://github.com
and @username you need to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask 
or https://stackoverflow.com
STR;

$pattern = "~(?<!\S)(?:(@[^\s@]+)(?!\S)[^h]*(?:h(?!ttp)[^h]*)*+)?\K((?:https?|ftp|file)://\S+)~";

$result = preg_replace_callback($pattern, function($m){
    return sprintf('<a href="%s">%s</a>', $m[2],$m[1] !== "" ?  $m[1] : $m[2]);
}, $string);

echo $result;
```

Output

```
Hello @username you need to check this <a href="http://github.com">@username</a>
and @username you need to <a href="https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask">@username</a> 
or <a href="https://stackoverflow.com">https://stackoverflow.com</a>
```

**Note**

If there can not occur an `@` between the username and the url, you could use `[^h@]*` instead of `[^h]*`

Comment: Hey @the-fourth-bird, Thanks for the great explanation, but when I write this comment 
`Hello @username check this https://regex101.com/r/D3Imn9/1` then link become username link and after username not getting any comment 
`Hello @username` then next comment is getting blank.

Comment: @KiranAjudiya I see what you mean. Do you mean like this? https://3v4l.org/poD0p I have updated the answer.

Comment: Yes @the-fourth-bird, I try it, when I need if user mention any user of site @username so I need `url('/')/profile/username`, now what is currently happen when I mention user and put link, link become username link, both are different things. I hope you got it.

Comment: @KiranAjudiya No problem, then you can mark that answer as accepted and I will delete mine.

Comment: sorry for your time, the above answer work for me. Thanks for helping me.

Comment: Keep your Answer bcoz, I learn new things for your explanation. maybe it's helpful for others.